# Getting error when trying to commit change to github ,fatal: remote origin already exists

Tags: git, github

I succeed to create remote repository into GitHub and also creating gh-pages to present some client page , now i like to commit change to single file but getting errors which i don't understand.
i followed this tutorial :
http://readwrite.com/2013/10/02/github-for-beginners-part-2
and got stacked in this part:

> git remote add origin https://github.com/username/myproject.git

Here is my commands :
Checking the status :
D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5>get status
'get' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

```
D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5>git status
# On branch gh-pages
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#
#       modified:   src/simplegame.js
#
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

cding to the source where i like to push to the remote repository (simplegame.js)

```
D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5>cd src

D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git add simplegame.js
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/simplegame.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.

D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git commit -m "www.foo.com Foo v0.1 syntax error"
[gh-pages warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/simplegame.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
6959bd7] www.foo.com Foo v0.1 syntax error
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in src/simplegame.js.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git remote add origin https://github.com/fooy/Foo-html5.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

and then im getting this error:
fatal: remote origin already exists.

then i try to execute those commands but still errors

```
D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git status
# On branch gh-pages
nothing to commit (working directory clean)

D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git push origin gh-pages
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://fooy@github.com':
To https://github.com/fooy/Foo-html5.git
 ! [rejected]        gh-pages -> gh-pages (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/fooy/Foo-html5.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
hint: before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

D:\dev\www.foo.com\Foo\git\Foo-html5\src>git push origin master
Username for 'https://github.com':
Password for 'https://fooy@github.com':
To https://github.com/fooy/Foo-html5.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/fooy/Foo-html5.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because a pushed branch tip is behind its remote
hint: counterpart. Check out this branch and merge the remote changes
hint: (e.g. 'git pull') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

what am i doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The remove master has advanced since you created your commit, so your commit cannot be pushed. There are several things you can do:

First, you could fetch the remote changes and rebase your changes on top of them:

```
$ git fetch origin

$ git rebase origin/master

$ git push origin master
```

Second, if you own the remote origin and are 100% sure you don't want the changes that appear there but not in your branch, you could force pushs

```
$ git push --force origin master
```

Comment: what ? i just want to simple commit file .. why i need to re base / and do all this ?

Comment: @user63898: in git, you don't really commit a (single) file: each commit is (a snapshot of) *every* file.  So if you're working together with other people, you must pick up their new changes and add them to your changes, otherwise your latest commit has the side effect of *un*-doing their work.  (It's more complicated than that, but this is why you need to read a git tutorial and learn how collaboration is done with git.)